# JavaScript query when zoomed in

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have successfully created a query for a feature layer. However, if I run the query while zoomed in, it only filters those graphics within view. When I zoom out, the areas that were not originally in view are not affected by the query.

Here is the site in question:
[Public Meeting Map](http://www.matthewiannowlin.com/publicmeetings)

[Here is the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgpvPV)

Comment: it would help if you could include the relevant code directly in your question, rather than making people open your app and hunt for it - you're more likely to get a good answer that way

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I definitely agree it wasn't the best way to present the question. I was posting this from mobile while stuck in a meeting. I edited the question to include a code pen link. Does that seem like the best way to do it? Rather than dumping all that script in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code here:

```
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureLayerURL,{
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    infoTemplate: popupTemplate,
    outFields: ["*"],
    maxRecordCount: null
});
```

try setting `mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND` to `mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT`. [More about FeatureLayer modes](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#constants).